# Using @Bean in @Component and @Configuration

Tags: java, spring

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

   @Bean
   public Student getStudent() {
       return new Student();
   }
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class Config {

   @Bean
   public Student getStudent() {
      return new Student();
   }
}
```

I want to know the difference of initializing bean to factory using above two approaches.

Answer (score 2):

There are a fundamentally different between the two `@Component` and `@Configuration` bean method registration.

If you declare `@Bean` method inside `@Configuration`, it will be wrapped into a CGLIB wrapper. Further call to the `@Bean` method return the same bean instance.

That is:

```
@Configuration
class A {
  @Bean
  BeanX getBeanX() { ... };

  @Bean
  BeanY getBeanY() {
     return new BeanY(getBeanX()); // You got the same bean instance from getBeanX() method, no matter how many times you call it
                                   // This instance is the container singleton instance
  }
}
```

If you use `@Component`, each time the bean method is called, another bean is created:

```
@Component
class B {
  @Bean
  BeanX getBeanX() { ... };

  @Bean
  BeanY getBeanY() {
     return new BeanY(getBeanX()); // You got the different bean instance every time you call it
                                   // This getBeanX() instance is different from container singleton instance
  }
}
```